# Is there a way to attach images to a question?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

I have a screenshot but I don't have a server to host it on.

Is there a way for me to just attach the image to the question?

Comment: Isn't this made obsolete by http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28525/?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.google.com/search?q=free+image+hosting

I've used ImageShack and ImgUr before without incident, though I think ImageShack may be blocked by some corporate firewalls.

or, we now support integrated image hosting using the image insert toolbar button:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/

Answer (score 5):

When using [the built-in image upload](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) no need to worry about anything. It happens to use imgur, but it uses a pro account, ensuring images will never expire.

For personal use, [imgur](http://imgur.com/) is good too if you want to throw up an image with no fuss. Images posted are allowed to stay up for a period of three (3) months with no activity before they are deleted. If you view your image before the three months are up, it'll be around.

If you want something where you can have an account, you can also try something like [Photobucket](http://photobucket.com/).

Whatever you do, don't go with TinyPic. They don't like it when you hotlink images (the whole point) and will only allow you a cruddy thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

I put images in my [dropbox](http://getdropbox.com) "public" folder, right click the file, "dropbox - copy public link". Very simple, no fuzz with upload forms.

Comment: But very prone to image rot. If you delete the image from Dropbox, it will be gone from your posts too. I hope meanwhile you're using [the image upload from the toolbar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) if your browser shows that?

Comment: @Arjan: If I use dropbox like this, I put the published files in a "permalink" folder to remind myself that I shouldn't delete or move them.

Comment: I still don't like that, as you can then still remove it anytime you like. I even doubt if it fits in [the TOS](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service), *[...] Content that You contribute [...] will be licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.* (You should be allowed [to remove your name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26851#26851), but not the content, if I understand correctly.)

Comment: Some [more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/does-the-cc-wiki-license-allow-the-licensor-to-withdraw-their-content-at-will/78172#78172): *You can stop distributing your work under a Creative Commons license at any time you wish; but this will not withdraw any copies of your work that already exist under a Creative Commons license from circulation.* I guess you could then delete your Dropbox file, and leave it up to others to make copies before that happens. Still, I don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

I use ImgUr and TinyPic.  I don't know what [random](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random)
is talking about when he says TinyPic only gives you a cruddy thumbnail.

[image]

To quickly produce images from the screen, I use [cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com), which is a basic, free , and extensible screen-shot tool, plus one or more of the [cropper plugins](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com) (also free). There's a "Send to Paint.NET" plugin for cropper if you want to doctor the image before uploading.  You can toggle from "Sent to Paint.NET" to "Send to TinyPic" easily, so...

1. snapshot (send to Paint.NET)
2. scribble on the image
3. snapshot (send to TinyPic, or ImgUr, or Flickr, etc)

It took 1 keystroke and about 3 seconds to get the image in this post up to TinyPic.

Comment: They may have relaxed things over at Tinypic, but there were a lot of posts using them that only rendered the shot useless and cruddy.

Answer (score 0):

I just use [Flickr](http://flicker.com) because I already have a Yahoo! account.