# attaching picture or file

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there a way to attach images to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/is-there-a-way-to-attach-images-to-a-question)
>   [How do I post a screenshot on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow)

how can i attach a file to a question for all or for a spacial person in here?

Comment: I have a feeling that wasn't really a worthwhile edit.

Comment: Also a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28525/how-do-i-post-a-screenshot-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Greg: "Spacial person" is obviously just a poor translation of alireza's language's word for "astronaut".

Comment: i'm not sure "astronaut" is what was meant by "spacial person" given the original `[matlab]` tag on this question.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to posting images:

- Gain at least 15 Rep (the minimum to post images)
- Upload them to an image hosting site.
- Click the picture icon above the space where you write/edit your post and copy the link location.

Comment: To get them into space you're going to need a laser.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the laser. I was busy burning out my fuse up here... alone.

Answer (score 0):

Host it on a file hosting service or on your server and link us to it.