# How can I show a picture?

Tags: support, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to attach images to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/is-there-a-way-to-attach-images-to-a-question)

I have an image on my computer. I want to display that image here. I try to copy and paste, but it is not possible. I also tried the HTML tag <"img src = "/home/user/Desktop/device.png">. How is it possibe?

Comment: define "here". On StackOverflow? On your website? Sounds like you are too new for stack.

Comment: "Here" as in "on Stackoverflow"? Well, we have no access to your computer, so we can't see images on your harddisk. You need to upload it to some public server so we can see it. Stackoverflow does this for you if you use the "Image" button.

Comment: the src is wrong it should be `www.stackoverflow.com/home/user/desktop/device.png` or something less weird.

Comment: Here first remove the double quote that you used before the img tag inside the angular brace as it is not allowed and include an alt attribute of the img tag. If instead of the image the alt msg is displayed u'll get to knw that the img tag is working fine and there is a problem with the source path of the image. For easier implementation, copy the image in the same folder as your html doc and only use the filename with its extension in its source attribute.. I hope this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="file:///Desktop/Something.png" />
```

That should be it. @[arex1337](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479911/arex1337), you forgot to close the tag.

Comment: You don't have to close the tag in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl + G then follow the instructions...

Comment: can u tell me which instruction i want to follow

Comment: you press the ctrl and G keys on your keyboard together then a popup will come up explaining how to upload the image

Answer (score 0):

Try beginning the url with `file://` like this:

```
<img src="file:///home/user/Desktop/device.png">
```

Comment: Oh, maybe you meant here on SO and not locally...