# Can I / should I delete unused images from Imgur?

Tags: support, imgur

I uploaded two images to [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) in the course of composing a question here. While *studying* the screenshots, I discovered the answer to my question, but the images remain. Now that I don't need them, will they [automatically expire after three months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26365/is-there-a-way-to-attach-images-to-a-question/26367#26367)? Or is the [new Imgur pro account](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/) going to keep around unlinked-images indefinitely?

I feel so wasteful.

Comment: Is this FAQ material?

Comment: I'm ambivalent.

Comment: Technically, they are not "unlinked" - there are still links to them in the revision history.

Comment: Since the newer question got official response, marking this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Can I delete unused images from imgur?

No, as the account belongs to SE, not you.

> Should I delete unused images from imgur?

N/A, but in theory, yes.

> Now that I don't need them, will they automatically expire after three months?

No.

> Or is the new imgur pro account going to keep around unlinked-images indefinitely?

Yes.

Comment: Then there's one last question to be asked: Does it matter? I.e., do you have a storage quota or is it unlimited?

Comment: @Aleadam, yes it most certainly **does** matter. What if the picture you upload happens to have personal data in it that you don't notice. If you edit the question and upload another photo with the personal information redacted, the original is still available under the post's revisions. Even if you edit it within 5 minutes, the photo is still there for the Imgur staff to access.

Comment: @Synetech If you uploaded personal data by mistake, you have the option to request a removal on http://imgur.com/removalrequest

Comment: You can do that for images on stack.imgur? Okay, then that’ll work. Though I don’t know why I keep reading references to a “deletion link” since there is no such link when uploading images on SE.