# Hide questions with a specific tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, facebook

In light of the recent influx of poorly worded Facebook-related questions, I would like to hide all questions with a Facebook tag.

[The Ability to Hide Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7603/the-ability-to-hide-questions) was asked in 2009.  Are there any updates to this request?

Comment: It would be better if you helped edit or vote to close the bad questions so that the site can be improved. Or if Stack Overflow made a 2 point rep minimum instead of 1 to ask (Facebook) questions.

Comment: @OffBySome patience exhausted :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook)* in your Profile in the Prefs tab, like so:

[image]

<sub><sub>* to ignore everything related to Facebook, add a star after `facebook`</sub></sub>

Comment: where is that ?

Comment: @FooBah: http://phpcode.eu/images/1316409329.png

Comment: You know, that is only visible if you try to go directly to stackoverflow.com and not from any /... page.  That looks exactly like what i want

Comment: @FooBah: sure I do

Comment: I edited in the better pic.  Please use the Insert Picture tool in the editor in the future, so we can avoid broken links.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: my server works, too. ImgUR deletes image after 3m after inactivity

Comment: Actually, according to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/can-i-should-i-delete-unused-images-from-imgur/94711#94711), SE has a Pro account, and the images will never be deleted.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: ah, good find. Didn't know this

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you could modify the GM script given in the main answer to filter by the tags you care about.

Having said that, a higher level of `ignore` might be a nice feature, if you only wanted some tags to be hidden and others not to be.  Otherwise [genesis' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106640/hide-questions-with-a-specific-tag/106642#106642) is what you want.