# How do I delete an unreferenced uploaded image?

Tags: support, images, imgur

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I / should I delete unused images from Imgur?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94710/can-i-should-i-delete-unused-images-from-imgur)

Today, while uploading an image to my question, I accidentally uploaded a personal photo. I didn't reference it anywhere. Is there any way of deleting it? Or, will it be kept forever? What happens to uploaded but unreferenced images?

Comment: See Adam Lear's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202719/172965).

Answer (score 1):

The is from the [imgur FAQ](https://imgur.com/faq#delete):

> Can I delete an image after I upload it?
>   **Yes**. At the bottom of the page, after you upload your image, you will see a section entitled "Deletion Links" that will contain everything you need to delete your image. However, be aware that this section only shows up immediately after you upload your image. This is to ensure that only you have seen them, and that only you are able to delete the image.
>
> If you have an account, then visit this page for info on how to delete your account images.
>
> **If you have lost your deletion links, you can still have your images deleted if you file a deletion claim here: [http://imgur.com/removalrequest](https://imgur.com/removalrequest)**

Comment: "[Can I delete unused images from imgur](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94710/168428)?" "[No, as the account belongs to SE, not you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94711/168428)."

Comment: @jadarnel27 still does not mean you that you cannot contact imgur to remove it...

Comment: And I could send you an e-mail and then ask your e-mail provider to delete it from your inbox because it's mine.

Comment: @jadarnel27 technically any picture you put up on facebook is theirs, but yet you can ask them to delete it.

Comment: What the... "Why should these images be removed ಠ_ಠ?"? __Won't runs imgur?!?!?!__