# How can I remove an image from Imgur?

Tags: support, imgur

I want to remove some photos from https://i.stack.imgur.com, because they are breaking my privacy (they contain my personal information). How can I do that or who should I ask to do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the contact form linked to at the bottom of any page and send us the links to the images you want removed.

Comment: Are you with imgur? Because I also have an image there with personal information that I've been trying for months to get removed, and all my requests have been ignored.

Comment: @user137369 No, I work at Stack Exchange. We can remove images hosted on our private Imgur instance (i.stack.imgur.com) but not Imgur proper.

Comment: Same here. Private image, requested removal. Nothing happens. No reply. Nothing. This is completely against data privacy regulations. Imgur should be sued for breaking the law.

Comment: @Avatar Did you contact Imgur or our support? If the images were uploaded to our Imgur instance (i.e. the image URL starts with `i.stack.imgur.com`), submit a removal request to our team through https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see now that the URL indeed starts with `https://i.stack.imgur.com/`. Maybe that's the reason why Imgur does not handle the case. Request sent to your team. 

Answer (score 7):

Go to Imgur and file a [removal request](https://imgur.com/removalrequest). If it contains personal information, I'm sure they'd comply with your request, even for images hosted on Stack's Imgur domain.

Comment: Ok, how long should I wait ?

Comment: @Ty221 6-8 weeks/months/years. Sometimes they act only upon DMCA Takedown requests, and it's their full right.