# Delete uploaded image

Tags: support, imgur

I accidentally uploaded an image in chat that contained some personal information. I deleted the chat message, but would like delete the image from imgur. I've seen [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94710/202832), with [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94711/202832) that says because "the account belongs to SE, not you" I cannot delete an image.

However, because *this* image contains personal information, it really must be deleted. How can I go about doing so?

Comment: See Adam Lear's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202719/172965) or use the [Imgur Removal Request Form](http://imgur.com/removalrequest).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention, explain why you need it removed. Specifically, explain why just editing it out or *deleting the post* isn't good enough.

If your explanation for the moderator indicates that there's a valid need, they'll pass it on to one of us & we'll nuke it.

Standard disclaimer: **there are no guaranteed take-backs on the 'Net.** If you post your password, change it immediately. If you post something of someone else's that you weren't supposed to, apologize to them. If you're hoping to re-write your own past, get over it and write a better future instead.

Comment: RE: "If you're hoping to re-write your own past, get over it and write a better future instead." Excellent advice!!! This also applies to so many who have been bullied over something online as well, though it might be said with a bit more sensitivity in that case. ;)

Comment: Are images already uploaded when they are shown as preview and before clicking "Add image" button ? (i guess not)

Comment: Not uploaded until you hit add, @intika

Comment: Is there a script that automatically checks for images that are not in any posts (removed by editing) and purges the images from the server automatically?

Comment: @Shog9 Don't you think that using words "_If you convince the moderator handling the flag that you're not crazy_" is a bit to harsh? Your answer seems to be suggesting that simple edit to the post is enough ("_explain why just editing it out or deleting the post isn't good enough_") and that calling moderator and asking for a permanent deletion of image is overreacting. That's so wrong. What good does edit give me, if anyone can see a link to "sensitive" image in edit history?

Comment: I know it sounds flippant, but... I wrote that after years of handling requests that were, if I were to put it most charitably, nonsense. Images that were both integral to the post and contained only information already present elsewhere in the post; images in other people's posts; images that had been present on the site for years; all images in all posts; etc.

Answer (score 11):

You can send a [removal request](https://imgur.com/removalrequest) directly to Imgur. I doubt they would deny a user's request to have an image with personal information purged from their records.

Comment: Is your answer valid as you wrote it before you were hired? I ask because of [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327525/delete-uploaded-picture-in-profile) and I wondered if contacting the team would be an option.

Comment: I requested the removal of a private image. Nothing happens. Weeks passed. No reply. Nothing. This is completely against data privacy regulations. Imgur should be sued for breaking the law.

Comment: Based on the claim given by OP in question (that images are uploaded to imgur using **SE's not user's account** I strongly doubt they'd do anything. Imagine that I am writing to you: please delete an image with the following link and you discover that this image was uploaded by some other account, not me. What would you do. Suggesting that imgur will do anything in this cases seems very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Mr. Shog was willing to delete it for me. <sup>[Chat message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3103167#3103167)</sup>