# Delete uploaded picture in profile (from i.stack.imgur.com hosting)

Tags: support, imgur

I opened a ticket to remove an uploaded image with sensitive data (uploaded by mistake), but it is impossible to get an answer.

What is the faster way to remove an image from the https://i.stack.imgur.com site?

Comment: The only way is through the contact form. Keep in mind that the company has been closed for the past week and it may take some time to receive a response as the community team starts processing tickets again.

Comment: thanks I will wait then. best wishes

Answer (score 1):

Just posting @animuson comment:

> The only way is through the contact form. Keep in mind that the company has been closed for the past week and it may take some time to receive a response as the community team starts processing tickets again.

And @AdamLear answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202719/842411)

> Use the contact form linked to at the bottom of any page and send us the links to the images you want removed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait...

[As former staff Shog mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250344/delete-uploaded-image/250349#250349):

> Flag it for moderator attention, explain why you need it removed. Specifically, explain why just editing it out or *deleting the post* isn't good enough.
>
> If you convince the moderator handling the flag that you're not crazy, they'll pass it on to one of us & we'll nuke it.
>
> Standard disclaimer: **there are no guaranteed take-backs on the 'Net.** If you post your password, change it immediately. If you post something of someone else's that you weren't supposed to, apologize to them. If you're hoping to re-write your own past, get over it and write a better future instead.

Comment: Hi! In response to [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com//transcript/message/54244421#54244421): yes, I'm suspended again on SO, absurdly enough :) It's because I'm sending comments to brand-new users pointing them to [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251298)...but I'm trying to get them to reconsider or at least explain precisely.

Comment: @richardec Ah man... That is harsh.